# Trying to tailor a query for search functionality without vba

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a pretty bare-bones search tool to pull records from a table ("ApplicationTable").  The user is presented with a form containing a number of textbox controls, each one corresponding to a field in the table (ApplicationID, FirstName, LastName, etc.)  They enter data into whatever field(s) they wish, then click a button.  The search should return each record for which a corresponding field contains the search parameter, and ignores any search field that is blank.  Data is displayed in a report that pops up.

For example, if you enter "A17" into the ApplicationID control, it'll return all records for which the ApplicationID field contains "A17".  If you enter "A17" into ApplicationID and "John" into FirstName, it'll return all records for which the ApplicationID field contains "A17" and the FirstName field contains "John".  If you hit the search button with all fields blank, it just returns all records in the table.

Unfortunately, for the life of me, I cannot get the SQL right to make this thing powered by a simple query, and so I'm having to use vba.  But I don't want to, because it's making a lot of things more complicated than it needs to be.  (e.g., I'm trying to export the results to Excel, which is a pain since transferspreadsheet can't accept dynamic SQL.)

SO!

Here is the vba code I'm using currently:

```
Dim QueryStr As String
Dim AddAnd As Boolean

AddAnd = False

If Not IsNull([Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![ApplicationID]) Then

    QueryStr = QueryStr & "((ApplicationTable.ApplicationID) Like '*' & 
     [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![ApplicationID] & '*')"
    AddAnd = True

End If

If Not IsNull([Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![NevadaApplicationID]) Then

    If AddAnd = True Then

        QueryStr = QueryStr & " AND "

    End If

    QueryStr = QueryStr & "((ApplicationTable.NevadaApplicationID) Like '*' 
     & [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![NevadaApplicationID] & '*')"
    AddAnd = True

End If

If Not IsNull([Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![FirstName]) Then

    If AddAnd = True Then

        QueryStr = QueryStr & " AND "

    End If

    QueryStr = QueryStr & "((ApplicationTable.ClaimantFirstName) Like '*' & 
     [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![FirstName] & '*')"
    AddAnd = True

End If

If Not IsNull([Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![LastName]) Then

    If AddAnd = True Then

        QueryStr = QueryStr & " AND "

    End If

    QueryStr = QueryStr & "((ApplicationTable.ClaimantLastName) Like '*' & 
     [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![LastName] & '*')"
    AddAnd = True

End If

If Not IsNull([Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![AssignedStaff]) Then

    If AddAnd = True Then

        QueryStr = QueryStr & " AND "

    End If

    QueryStr = QueryStr & "((ApplicationTable.AssignedStaff) Like '*' & 
     [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![AssignedStaff] & '*')"
    AddAnd = True

End If

If Not IsNull([Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![VictimDescription]) Then

    If AddAnd = True Then

        QueryStr = QueryStr & " AND "

    End If

    QueryStr = QueryStr & "((ApplicationTable.VictimDescription) Like '*' & 
     [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![VictimDescription] & '*')"
    AddAnd = True

End If

DoCmd.OpenReport "ClientSearchQuery", acViewReport, , QueryStr
```

"ClientSearchQuery" is the core query I'm using, without any filters on it:

```
SELECT ApplicationTable.PrimaryAppID, ApplicationTable.ApplicationID, ApplicationTable.NevadaApplicationID, 
  ApplicationTable.EarliestReceivedDate, ApplicationTable.ClaimantFirstName, ApplicationTable.ClaimantLastName,
  ApplicationTable.AssignedStaff, ApplicationTable.ContactDate, ApplicationTable.VictimDescription
  FROM ApplicationTable;
```

Help?  I assume I need to use iifs to get this thing going with just SQL, but I couldn't get the syntax right, and it would either throw an error or return the wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean logic to the rescue!

Make your static query like this, and you won't need any VBA.

```
SELECT stuff
  FROM ApplicationTable
 WHERE (ApplicationID Like '*' & [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![ApplicationID] & '*'
        OR [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![ApplicationID] IS NULL)
   AND (NevadaApplicationID Like '*' & [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![NevadaApplicationID] & '*'
        OR [Forms]![ClientSearchForm]![NevadaApplicationID] IS NULL)
   AND ...
```

For each of the AND clauses, if the respective search control is NULL, then the clause is always TRUE.

Note: for a working VBA solution, see http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html