# Is there a better way in writing a where clause in access vba

Tags: ms-access

Here is a little brain teaser!

I have a query that has at least 3 different where clauses. Instead of writing an elaborate if statement to test every single possible outcome, I am wondering if there is a simpler way of doing it!

These 3 clauses are chosen from drop down menus that have at least 3 x different values including an "ALL" option.

I hope you guys are starting to se my issue...

so if I have:

```
SELECT * FROM tabe1 WHERE col1 = combo1Value AND col2 = combo2Value AND col3 = combo3Value
```

USER decides to select the following:

- combo1: All
- combo2: item (an option that is not all)
- combo3: item (an option that is not all)

so now is there a way to re-write my query:

```
WHERE col1 = * AND col2 = combo2value AND col3 = combo3value
```

or I have no choice but to write a big if-statement???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to tailor a query for search functionality without vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715023/trying-to-tailor-a-query-for-search-functionality-without-vba)

Comment: Just change `IS NULL` in the answer to `= "*"`.

Comment: the IIF worked great see answer below ( @Gustav ) with my comment on how I modified it to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
WHERE 
    col1 = IIf([combo1value] = "*", [col1], [combo1value]) AND 
    col2 = IIf([combo2value] = "*", [col2], [combo2value]) AND 
    col3 = IIf([combo3value] = "*", [col3], [combo3value])
```

Comment: thank you for the idea!! this is what I had to do! "... WHERE col1 = " & val1 & " AND " & IIf(variable <> "ALL", "col2 = '" & variable & "'", 1 = 1), where 1=1 is like returning true and variable is a variable that holds the word ALL or other values depending on the combo box values. Thank you for helping me out!